# Expression must have pointer-to-class-type error

Tags: c++

Assume that I have the following classes:

```
class a {
  xyz();
  Foo foo;
}

class Foo {
  classB();
  run();
}
```

I would like to call the `run()` method from another method:

```
int a::xyz{
  foo = new Foo();
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, myfunc, foo);
  return 0;
}

void *a::myfunc(void* _msg) {
  _msg->run(); 
}
```

but I am receiving *Expression must have pointer-to-class-type* error on the line where I called `run()`

What can I use to solve the problem?

Comment: where are the return types of the methods?

Comment: What is the type of the `foo` attribute in class `a`? When you answer that question, you will know where you went wrong. Alternatively, read the error message again a couple of times. And when you're done with that, be sure to remember that C++ is not Java or C# and that `new` is an operator you will not be using very often.

Comment: @dandan78 `Foo` is the `Foo` class.

Comment: Exactly. But that's not how you are treating it.

Comment: @dandan78 I made another edit in `myfunc`. I needed to call `_msg->run()`

Comment: @www Sorry, but your short code example is full of problems. You're going to have to go back to the basics because Stackoverflow is not the place for questions of this sort.

Comment: you should include the declaration of myfunc, and the return types for the methods in Foo. I.e. you should provide a SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `static_cast<Foo *>(_msg)->run()`.

Your _msg is a `void *`. You can't call methods on that; the compiler needs to know the type of the object being pointed to, in order to determine which methods you can call. The cast to `Foo *` tells the compiler the correct type.

Comment: @www, very well, I have changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes now this works! I was not casting as you mentioned.

Comment: `static_cast<Foo *>(_msg)->run()` is the C++-style equivalent.

Comment: @www please accept the answer if you found it to be correct.

Comment: @davmac Ops, forgot that. Sorry.